# What's the ZPL command for "page-break" on continious vs mark-based labels?

Tags: zpl

I need help finding out the appropriate ZPL-command for issuing a "page-break".

If the labels are continious I imagine it's a ^LL-job, and if existing, add a cutter command.

But for pre-printed (with optical delimiters), how do I feed to "next label"?

I guess the ~JS command is involved, can't just get it together. Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Can you add more details about your media?  If it is continuous, then use ^LL.  If it is pre-preprinted and continuous you would likely need another way to calibrate, for example a black mark on the back of the media.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The thing is, I'm writing a class to convert XHTML to ZPL and currently don't have any printer at hand. I understand the problems around needing to feed to cutter and then backfeeding before next job. But backfeeding is made at start of job, right?

Comment: The back feed is based on printer settings for Print Mode (Tear Off, Rewind, Peel, Cutter, Applicator) and the Tear Off position that allows you to fine tune the position forward or backward based on the media.  I may be misunderstanding, but I have never had to code the back feed, that would happen automatically based on the printer's configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finish current label with ^XZ and start a new one with ^XA. This would result in label feed to the length set in ^LL.

Answer (score 1):

I was working with ZPL commands with a little Windows Application Form to print Labels with a GK420t printer and I just had to repeat a segment of the ZPL commands sequence

Only check this sequence:

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR5,5~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW456
^LL0252
^LS0
^FT436,201^A0I,28,31^FH\^FDProducto de Prueba 1^FS
^BY3,2,149^FT379,40^BEI,,Y,N
^FD0123456789012^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

^XA
^MMT
^PW456
^LL0252
^LS0
^FT436,201^A0I,28,31^FH\^FDProducto de Prueba 2^FS
^BY3,2,149^FT379,40^BEI,,Y,N
^FD0123456789012^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

^XA
^MMT
^PW456
^LL0252
^LS0
^FT436,201^A0I,28,31^FH\^FDProducto de Prueba 3^FS
^BY3,2,149^FT379,40^BEI,,Y,N
^FD0123456789012^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

I hope this could help you!